Por que no funciona el codigo? Cuando realizo la peticion dice que fue exitosa, pero no llega el formulario al mail seleccionado, alguna idea?
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import uvicorn
import os

app = FastAPI()

# Allow requests from your frontend
orig_client = ["http://localhost:3000"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=orig_client,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

class Form(BaseModel):
    name: str
    secondName: str
    locality: str
    province: str
    phoneNumber: str

@app.post("/send-email")
async def send_email(form: Form):
    try:
        email = SendEmail(
            receiver_email="example@example.com",  # Use a placeholder email here
            subject="Nuevo Contacto desde el formulario",
            content=f"""
            Nombre: {form.name}
            Segundo Nombre: {form.secondName}
            Localidad: {form.locality}
            Provincia: {form.province}
            Numero de telefono: {form.phoneNumber}
            """
        )
        return {'message': 'Email sent successfully'}
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

class SendEmail:
    def __init__(self, receiver_email: str, subject: str, content: str) -> None:
        self.email = os.getenv('EMAIL_USER', 'your-email@example.com')  # Use default value or environment variable
        self.password = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASS', 'your-password')  # Use default value or environment variable
        self.receiver_email = receiver_email
        self.subject = subject
        self.content = content
        self.send_email()

    def send_email(self) -> bool:
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = self.email
        msg['To'] = self.receiver_email
        msg['Subject'] = self.subject
        msg.attach(MIMEText(self.content, 'plain'))

        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            server.starttls()
            server.login(self.email, self.password)
            server.sendmail(self.email, self.receiver_email, msg.as_string())
            server.quit()
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error sending email:', str(e))
            return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)


No se si sea válido enviar correos desde un método asíncrono. Tendrías que revisar eso.

Seguro que el correo no está en spam o algo así?

No se puede enviar un correo, a secas, desde el SMTP de Gmail. Desde el panel de control de Google debes autorizar una App para que pueda enviar correos desde tus scripts. Busca en internet más información al respecto.
